# Built-in filter for synonyms in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to Elasticsearch and writing an analyzer that should analyze a word into its synonyms.
I read [the Elasticsearch document](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-synonym-tokenfilter.html) but as far as I found, I should have a synonym file and refer to this file in a custom filter.
I have 1000 documents to search, so I certainly can't write synonyms for all words. finally, my question is there is another way like any built-in filter that does this work?